# Can Not Is Nothing determine if an item has a category?

Tags: vba, outlook

A macro at work, in a shared mailbox, doesn’t always trigger correctly.

Is

```
If objItem.Categories <> "" Then
```

as ‘effective’ as

```
If Not objItem.Categories Is Nothing Then
```

Alternatively, would a select case statement with 60 case outcomes not trigger correctly?

Comment: It's not a question of it being effective. A `Nothing` is something entirely different than an empty string. If `Categories` does not have data, does it return an empty string? or does it return a `Nothing`? Use the appropriate one.

Comment: "Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item."  - so don't use `Nothing` here.  I'm not sure there's any issue with large `Select Case` block - do you have some reason to suspect that's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MailItem.Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories) property returns a string representing the categories assigned to the Outlook item.

In VBA you can just check whether it is an empty string or not. So, the following check is correct:

```
If objItem.Categories <> "" Then …
```